# Dynamic or xhr Templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have just started using backbone.js for a project that I am working on.

I currently have everything set up the way I want it as far as the models,collections and views.  I am getting data from a REST application on my server.

Clients are able to log into the app; currently I am feeding that information into an underscore.js template but I want the template to be dynamic.  Some options are going to be different depending on the client.

My feeling is that having the template make specific ajax calls to get dynamic information would defeat the purpose of using backbone.js altogether.  Is it possible to have backbone and underscore load a template from an xhr request? Or is there an even better way to do this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is just a string as far as Underscore is concerned so you can get that string from anywhere you want. So you could do this:

```
render: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get('/some_template', function(tmpl) {
        that.$el.html(_.template(tmpl, that.model.toJSON()));
    });
    return this;
}
```

In real life you'd probably want to hide that behind a simple caching object that only fetches a particular template from the server once.

Or, you could let your server code figure out which set of templates are needed and embed them in `<script>` elements:

```
<script id="tmpl1" type="text/template">
    Some template code...
</script>
<script id="tmpl2" type="text/template">
    Some template code...
</script>
...
```

and pull the templates out of the `<script>`s:

```
render: function() {
    var tmpl = _.template($('#tmpl1').html());
    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

And again you might want to cache the compiled template, `tmpl`, somewhere or even compile it while defining the view class (assuming that the DOM is ready enough of course):

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#tmpl1').html()),
    //...
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```